# Can't move animated rig around the scene

Tags: animation

I have successfully managed to create a human rig and have the figure follow motion trackers taken from a video of myself moving.

Now I want to take the entire moving rig and shift it on the x-axis, then start adding another rig into the scene (two people interacting). However I can't move the trackers for the first completed rig. They seem to be locked in place.

How do I move the entire animated rig, motion trackers and all, to another position in the scene?

Thanks for any help.